# Regular expression to remove string between brackets

Tags: regex

1. My string is like this  : Name   (CLOSED)
2. My string is like this  : Name   (CLOSED 0FF)
3. My string is like this  : Name   (CLOSED OF)
4. My string is like this  : Name   (DEC'D)

I want to remove both brackets and string inside the brackets, to get only : Name

I'm using this URL  http://regexr.com/ and I have written regx like this: ([()]CLOSED)

However, the last bracket is not getting selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just have to point out - you can't remove anything with regex! You can use regex to **find text** that should be removed (or in the case of most tools and languages - replaced). If you just want to use *regexr*, fine. Otherwise a language/tool should always be tagged. Also, FYI, try [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T3xxw7/3). That'll give you an explanation to why your own regex is failing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why Estebans answer doesn't work for you, but at least this should:

Replace

```
\s*\([^)]*\)
```

with nothing (empty string).

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iBAspe/1) (it appears regexr doesn't save the substitution string so I used regex101 instead).

Comment: Looks Good. Could you please give any tutorial reference?

Comment: That's one thing that's good with regex101 - it does that for you :) See upper right corner for explanation. Anyway, here a brief one: It matches any number of white-space characters `\s` (`*` - quantifier meaning 0 - infinite). Thereafter a left bracket (brackets have to be escaped - \ - since they have special meaning in regex), followed by any number och characters that **isn't** a right bracket (the character class - inside `[]` is negated by the commencing `^`). Finally it matches the right bracket. Matching this, and replacing it with an empty string will give the desired effect ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove parens at the end of string:

```js
\s*\([^()]*\)$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/AHcrmK/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex : `([\s]*[(][^)]*[)])`

This will match any space character following by `(` following by any character which is not `)` and `)`

If what you want is specifically the `CLOSED` text, just use : `([\s]*[(]CLOSED[)])`

See http://regexr.com/3g2sl

Comment: Or simpler: `\s*\([^)]*\)\s*` (imo).

Comment: @ClasG Yep, I agree with you, but the language was not specified, so I opted for the most portable one trying to reduce escaping

Comment: I am not aware of any regex flavour where you have to put predefined character classes in `[]` to use them.

Comment: @Joey I was refering to escaping the `(` and `)`. As for character class, depending on the language, it could be `[:s:]` instead of `\s`, so the it could also minimize the error in translating the regex in the desired language as it is not specified. But sure, you do not have to put it inside bracket ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one 
 `([()]CLOSED.)`

Comment: This will match any character following `CLOSED`, not `CLOSED` inside parenthesis

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and demonstrate that it actually works with some real positive and negative examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try This `([(]CLOSED[)])`
You forgot to add the closing brackets